# Custom Javascript library: Add event listener to dynamically added html

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-listener, dynamic-html

I'm trying to build a Javascript library like jQuery just to learn Javascript more. So far, I've developed this:

```
window.jsLib = function (selector) {
    var about = {
        Version: 0.1
    };
    if (selector) {
        if (window === this) {
            return new jsLib(selector);
        }
        if (typeof selector === 'string') {
            var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                this[i] = nodes[i];
            }
            this.length = nodes.length;
        } else if (typeof selector === 'object') {
            this[0] = selector;
            this.length = 1;
        }
        return this;
    } else {
        return about;
    }
};
```

And for methods, I've developed  some like:

```
jsLib.fn = jsLib.prototype = {
    css: function (key, value) {
        if (value !== undefined) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                this[i].style[key] = value;
            }
            return this;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                return this[i].style[key];
            }
        }
    },
    html: function (value) {
        if (value !== undefined) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                this[i].innerHTML = value;
            }
            return this;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                return this[i].innerHTML;
            }
        }
    },
    on: function (type, callback) {
        console.log(window.event);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].addEventListener(type, callback, false);
        }
        return this;
    },
    trigger: function (type) {
        var event = new Event(type);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        return this;
    },
    append: function(value) {
        var old = this.html();
        this.html(old + '' + value);
        return this;
    }
};
```

You may have noted that I've defined a method `on` like jQuery.

Whenever I'm calling like `jsLib('div#foo').on('click', someFunc);`, it is working fine.

But, suppose I have appended some html like `jsLib('body').append('<a id="#bar" href="#">Click</a>');`

And then I want to provide an API to add event listener to `#bar` like `jsLib('body').on('click', '#bar', someOtherFunc);`.

But I'm not sure how to implement this listener.

Kindly help.

Comment: You already did, you can reuse your function 'on' which you mentioned is working fine!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The `on` method is working fine for the elements already loaded. But I want to add a listener for an element which is yet to be created. Can you please provide an example of how to reuse the `on` method?

Comment: You have to wait until the element exists. I am not sure how this is done. You best shot would be to look at the jQuery source code for that particular method. I probably does what ready does for those stone-age browsers; to constantly be checking using a timer!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments I suppose you request a live implementation?

If that is the case, i wold suggest you to add a data method to your object, remember all events to be registered and register them from append method, when content is appended to the current element.

I extended your library with the .data and .live methods and queued an event registration for the next span to be added in body. See the modified code snippet and check out the console to validate.

```js
window.jsLib = function (selector) {
    var about = {
        Version: 0.1
    };
    if (selector) {
        if (window === this) {
            return new jsLib(selector);
        }
        if (typeof selector === 'string') {
            var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                this[i] = nodes[i];
            }
            this.length = nodes.length;
            this._selector = selector;
        } else if (typeof selector === 'object') {
            this[0] = selector;
            this.length = 1;
        }
        return this;
    } else {
        return about;
    }
};

jsLib.fn = jsLib.prototype = {
    css: function (key, value) {
        if (value !== undefined) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                this[i].style[key] = value;
            }
            return this;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                return this[i].style[key];
            }
        }
    },
    html: function (value) {
        if (value !== undefined) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                this[i].innerHTML = value;
            }
            return this;
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                return this[i].innerHTML;
            }
        }
    },
    on: function (type, callback) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].addEventListener(type, callback, false);
        }
        return this;
    },
    trigger: function (type) {
        var event = new Event(type);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        return this;
    },
    append: function(value) {
        var old = this.html(),
            pendingEvents = this.data('jsLib_Future_Events') || [],
            registered = {};
        
        this.html(old + '' + value);
        
        // Attach pending events to newly added childs (if any match found)
        pendingEvents.forEach(function (evConf, i) {
         [].slice.call(jsLib(this._selector + ' ' + evConf.selector), 0).forEach(function (el) {
             jsLib(el).on(evConf.type, evConf.callback);
                registered[i] = true;
            });
        }.bind(this));
        
        // Clear list of pending requests of any registered events
        this.data('sLib_Future_Events', pendingEvents.filter(function (evConf, i) { return !!registered[i]; }));
        
        return this;
    },
    _data: {},
    data: function (key, value) {
        if (arguments.length > 1) this._data[key] = arguments[1];   // Setter
        return key ? this._data[key] : this._data;     // Getter of key or all
    },
    live: function (type, selector, callback) {
        this.data('jsLib_Future_Events', (this.data('jsLib_Future_Events') || []).concat({type: type, selector: selector, callback: callback}));
        return this;
    }
};

jsLib('body').live('click', 'span', function () { console.debug('event triggered on appendend content after live registration of event handle'); });

jsLib('body').append('<br><span>dynamic content</span>');
```

```html
<div>existing content</div>
```

Considerations:

- you will have to make a similar implementation for html method
- if you want to make a real live clone you will have to keep pre-registered event definitions and register any new elements matching the selector (at this moment once an element matches the selector and the event is registered the event definition is removed in append - to make it universal you will have to mark your bound elements, use data for this)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It looks like it will work the way I want. I will surely do some tests and revert.